# Use same page for multiple routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to find out how to use the same page for multiple routes on a Nuxt.js with i18n module.

Basically I want this route: `/product-category/:slug/in/:material` to use the same page as `/product-category/:slug`

So far I have tried below, adding it to nuxt.config.js - but it doesn't work. It simply shows the `_slug/_material/index.vue` file.

```
router: {
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
        routes.push({
            path: '/product-category/:slug/in/:material',
            component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/product-category/_slug/index.vue')
        })
    }
},
```

Maybe because I am having the i18n module, maybe because I am doing something wrong.

This is my folder structure:

[image: ed]

If I inspect my router.js file, I see the path shown twice:

[image]

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - what does it mean exactly ?

Comment: @MichalLevý I have updated my question with more precise information. tldr; it shows the `_slug/_materiale/index.vue` file

Answer (score 2):

This was my workaround, I just wish there was a simpler method. Plus it still works if you use nuxt i18n.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
router: {
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
        const routesToAdd = [
            { // add your routes here
                name: 'product-category-slug-material',
                path: '/product-category/:slug/in/:material',
                component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/product-category/_slug/index.vue'), // which component should it resolve to?
                chunkName: 'pages/product-category/_slug/_material/index' // this part is important if you want i18n to work
            }
        ];

        const existingRoutesToRemove = routesToAdd.map(route => route.name);

        const generateRoutes = routes.filter((route) => {
            return !existingRoutesToRemove.includes(route.name);
        });

        routesToAdd.forEach(({ name, path, component, chunkName }) => {
            generateRoutes.push({
                name,
                path,
                component,
                chunkName
            });
        });

        routes.splice(0, routes.length, ...generateRoutes); // set new array
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.vue` to catch everything.

> If you do not know the depth of your URL structure, you can use _.vue to dynamically match nested paths. This will handle requests that do not match a more specific request.

[Here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/) you can find out more.